# Accesing Controls in Excel VBA Userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating form controls in a custom userform and have having difficulty in accesing them after creation.  The amount of ComboBoxes and TextBoxes depends on user input.  I am using a CommandButton to figure the correct syntax, but am at a loss to find the control.  I have used several different naming conventions inside the CommandButton_Click method and nothing works.

My code for the userform to create my controls is as follows:

```
Sub createDetails()

Dim details As Variant


details = TextBox3.Value
remainTot = TextBox2.Value

If TextBox3.Value = "" Or TextBox3.Value = 0 Then
MsgBox "Must have at least 1 detail"
Exit Sub
Else
End If


For i = 1 To details

n = i - 1

Dim SubPay As Control
Dim CatPay As Control
Dim AmtPay As Control

Set theLbl = frmInvoice.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lbl_" & i, True)
    With theLbl
      .Caption = "Detail " & i
      .Left = 20
      .Width = 60
      .Top = n * 24 + 110
      .Font.Size = 10
    End With


Set SubPay = frmInvoice.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "SubComboBox_" & i, True)
    With SubPay
        .Top = 108 + (n * 24)
        .Left = 60
        .Height = 18
        .Width = 100
        .Name = "subBox" & i
        .Font.Size = 10
        .TabIndex = n * 3 + 6
        .TabStop = True
        .RowSource = "PayeeList"
    End With

Set CatPay = frmInvoice.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "CatComboBox_" & i, True)
    With CatPay
        .Top = 108 + (n * 24)
        .Left = 165
        .Height = 18
        .Width = 100
        .Name = "catBox" & i
        .Font.Size = 10
        .TabIndex = n * 3 + 7
        .TabStop = True
        .RowSource = "CatList"
    End With

Set AmtPay = frmInvoice.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "AmtTextBox" & i, True)
    With AmtPay
        .Top = 108 + (n * 24)
        .Left = 270
        .Height = 18
        .Width = 50
        .Name = "amtBox" & i
        .Font.Size = 10
        .TabIndex = n * 3 + 8
        .TabStop = True

    End With

Next i

Dim TBox As Control

Set TBox = frmInvoice.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "TotalLbl", True)
    With TBox
        .Top = 130 + ((details - 1) * 24)
        .Left = 270
        .Height = 18
        .Width = 50
        .Name = "totBox"
        .Font.Size = 10
        '.TabIndex = (details - 1) * 3 + 9
        .TabStop = False
        .Value = TextBox2.Value

    End With


Set theLbl = frmInvoice.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "totLbl", True)
    With theLbl
      .Caption = "Total"
      .Left = 225
      .Width = 40
      .Top = 135 + ((details - 1) * 24)
      .Font.Size = 10
    End With

frmInvoice.Height = 200 + details * 24
With CommandButton1
.Top = 150 + details * 24
.TabStop = True
.TabIndex = (details - 1) * 3 + 9
End With

With CommandButton2
.Top = 150 + details * 24
.TabStop = False
'.TabIndex = (details - 1) * 3 + 10
End With



End Sub
```

The code for the CommndButton which doesn't work is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

frmInvoice.Controls("amtBox1").Value = 1
frmInvoice.Controls(amtBox1).Value = 2
frmInvoice.Controls(AmtTextBox1).Value = 3
frmInvoice.Controls("AmtTextBox1").Value = 4

End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Screen shot of my userform:

[image: My userform]

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: @Alok I am not getting any errors.  I simply can't set values in the new controls I have created or setfocus for that matter.  I am unable to find the correct name syntax.

Comment: I hope that sub createDetails is getting called before you click on CommandButton. can you confirm that?

Comment: @Alok Yes. The sub runs when I exit a textBox, creates the controls and then I manually try to click the command button.

Comment: Well, I was able to see the values getting set though I had to comment the lines which were settting Rowsource property for combo boxes. Can you check if the form that you see finally has all controls visible that you have created though code. May be the controls are not fully visible. If possible, please share a screen shot.

Comment: @Alok I attached the userform.  Detail 1, 2 and 3 were created when I exited TextBox3 which coincidentally has the value of three.  I am trying to keep a reverse running total in the textbox which shows a value of 1200.00.  As an amount is entered into each detail line, I want the total to reduce by that amount.  I just can't seem to find the values in each textbox  in the amount column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146472/discussion-between-alok-and-john-wolfenstein).

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
frmInvoice.Controls("amtBox1").Text
```

instead of

```
frmInvoice.Controls("amtBox1").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error because of

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

frmInvoice.Controls("amtBox1").Value = 1  'is true
frmInvoice.Controls(amtBox1).Value = 2    'is false because there isn't double quotes
frmInvoice.Controls(AmtTextBox1).Value = 3 'is false because  there isn't dobule quotes
frmInvoice.Controls("AmtTextBox1").Value = 4 'is false the AmtTextBoxt1 name is changed "amtBox1"

End Sub
```

[image]

Maby, Do you want to this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim total As Currency
    With frmInvoice
        For i = 1 To TextBox3.Value
                total = total + .Controls("amtBox" & i).Value
        Next i
        .Controls("totBox").Text = Format(total, "####.00")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I never used all four at the same time.  I commented out three and tried one at a time. None ever worked.

Comment: In my testing, first is doing well.

Comment: I am perplexed.  I must have some code somewhere that is affecting my ability to access the textbox.  It still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @JohnWolfenstein:  What yo do, get total? I modified my code.

Comment: I rewrote my code and it seems to be working.  There was a bug somewhere.